# Rails lightbox2 ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm trying to implement lightbox2 into a rather simple rails 5 app and seem to be getting the following error:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/lightbox/bpo.jpg"):`

Ive been following steps from: https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ & https://github.com/gavinkflam/lightbox2-rails

All images for the Lightbox are located within "images/lightbox" folder & images are properly displayed on the page however upon clicking on an image to enlarge and bring up the Lightbox modal the above routing error is displayed in the logs & no image appears.

```
gallery_controller.rb

def index
 @images = Dir.chdir(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images')) do
    Dir.glob('lightbox/*.jpg')
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% @images.each do |image| %>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href='<%= "images/#{image}" %>' class="img-fluid" data-lightbox="my-images">
              <%= image_tag image, class: "img-fluid" %>
            </a>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following has been added to my application.html.erb file
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` just before the closing body tag.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm confused on how to proceed.

Comment: Whould you share the output of `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` from rails console?

Comment: See below as it was too large to fit in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jus try this code snippet.

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% @images.each do |image| %>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href='<%= image_path(image) %>' class="img-fluid" data-lightbox="my-images">
              <%= image_tag image, class: "img-fluid" %>
            </a>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to use `image_path` helper method for `href` because assets are coming from through asset pipeline.

Comment: Thankyou very much! fixed the problem, and was a very simple explanation that I had overlooked (I'm still a bit of a beginner). Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

I've never used lightbox2 before
but if it's me, I would take 3 different solutions

1. change "a" into "div"
2. remove href from "a"
3. overwrite event handler of lightbox to preventDefault

hope any of those can solve your problem